# How to force ScrollController to recalculate position.maxExtents?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a desktop-style scrollbar, that changes it's size based on the size of the content. My scrollbar shares a ScrollController with a list, and relies on the position.maxExtents to know how large the content area is.

The issue is that when I change the number of rows, the maxExtents will not update, until a scrollEvent is initiated.

I've worked around it with code like this, moving 1px up, and 1px down over 100ms:

```
widget.controller.jumpTo(controller.position.pixels + 1);
Future.microtask(() => widget.controller.animateTo(controller.position.pixels - 1, duration: 100.milliseconds, curve: Curves.linear));
```

Which works pretty quite well when the list can scroll. However, when the list is < the height of the view, it can't scroll, and these calls have no effect, and I'm stuck with a stale maxExtents.

How can I just tell the list: "Hey, list, recalculate your children!"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay your code to when the controller has been updated using the following.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ...your code which requires controller's max extents...   
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't have that code in front of me anymore. But iirc, the issue was that the size was literally not recalculated until the list was physically scrolled, either by touch, or programmatically. This is why I had to force it to scroll 1px.

Comment: I have jumped into this problem today. Just my guess, the controller does recalculate the extent, but the new value is only available when the build cycle ends. When you change your scrollable content and execute the code right after that, it is still within the build cycle at the old state. And the postFrameCallback does the job deferring your code to when the new value of extent is ready.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the issues you've mentioned, animating the scroll position will cause Flutter to draw frames unnecessarily.

Borrowing from [@ltk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14521881/ltk) and [@Rakaton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7338957/rakaton), I think there's a simpler and more efficient way to do this:

```dart
// Run this code whenever the layout changes (i.e. any time you setState
// to update the list content)
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  widget.scrollController.position.notifyListeners();
});
```

You may also want to wrap your list component in a `SizeChangedLayoutNotifier` to detect size changes from things like window resize:

```dart
NotificationListener<SizeChangedLayoutNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      scrollController.position.notifyListeners();
    });
    return true;
  },
  child: SizeChangedLayoutNotifier(
    child: ListView(
      // ...
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider to use force pixels, but it's a protected method so it's gonna give you a warning. And I don't know about the performance or another stuffs about it.

```
widget.controller.position.forcePixels(controller.position.pixels + 1);
```

or combination of correct pixels and notifylistener.

```
widget.controller.position.correctPixels(controller.position.pixels + 1);
widget.controller.position.notifyListeners();
```